# fbsdkmessagedialog callback for iOS

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-messenger, facebook-messages

I'm new to IOS programming, I'm trying to send message to Facebook friends using the below

```
[FBSDKMessageDialog showWithContent:content delegate:(id)self];
```

I have added callback as below:

```
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
{
    NSLog(@"complete");
}

- (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer
{
    NSLog(@"Cancelled")
}
```

But the sharer method is not called when I send a message in FB messenger rather the `sharerDidCancel` is called. The `sharerDidCancel` method is called when user cancels or send a message, how can I differentiate send vs cancel?

Comment: I am suffering from same case, if you have fixed your issue please let us know how you fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, no luck so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has a [confirmed bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1069478703071265/) concerning this, however the addressed bug there is that it always calls `sharer:didCompleteWithResults` instead of `sharerDidCancel`.

[Their next release contain a fix for this](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1069478703071265/?comment_id=136400420058290) (v45) and hopefully this fixes our bug too (I'm having the same problem).